# How to count occurrences of each potential variable and find their proportions in R?

Tags: r

Ultimately, I am trying to find the proportions of each potential variable in each subgroup.

I have a large data frame (Patient1) with 108.720 rows that includes:

- factor variable Majority_SNP (Could be A, T, C, G, or dash)
- Index location (1 to 9.060)
- many, many other things

I want to eventually do a chart showing the relative frequencies of A, T, C, G, and dashes are the "Majority_SNP" by index location.  Something like:

| Index | Proportion A | Proportion G | Proportion C | Proportion T | Proportion dash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 0.15 | 0.25 | 0 | 0.35 | 0.25 |

I have tried:

```
Pt1_Majority_SNP_Counts_by_Loci <-
 Patient1 %>%
 group_by(Index) %>%
 table(Majority_SNP)
```

but I get the following error:

> "Error in table(., Majority_SNP) : object 'Majority_SNP' not found"

But I know that Majority_SNP is something previously saved in R because the following works fine.

```
table(Patient1$Majority_SNP)
```

Comment: Hi, Teddy. Have you attempted to use prop.table()? In this case, your instinct regarding table() was right on, and wrapping that in prop.table() will return proportions. In this case: 

prop.table(table(Patient1$Majority_SNP))

Let me know if this accomplishes what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This code sends the `data.frame` to `table`, but `table` works with a vector

```
 Patient1 %>%
 table(Majority_SNP)
```

Another approach would be to use the operator `$` from `magrittr`

```
 Patient1 %$%
 table(Majority_SNP)
```

Or `with` from R Base

```
with(Patient1 , table(Majority_SNP))
```

Comment: How do I get it to group it by index number though?

Comment: In `dplyr` we have the function `count`,  if you want to count both variables this may help you `Patient1 %>% count(Index,Majority_SNP)`

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a table with three rows, one being the index number, one with A, T, C, G, or dash, and the other with 12 (which is the number of rows in the original data frame with any given index number). It doesn't give me the break down of, for example, 3 A's, 4 G's, 3 T's, 1 C, 1 dash

Answer (score 0):

If we need to use `table` on the column outside the `dplyr` function, `pull` the column

```
library(dplyr)
Patient1 %>%
    pull(Majority_SNP) %>%
    table
```

Or with `.$`

```
Patient1 %>%
    table(.$Majority_SNP)
```